# libGDX AssetManager file not found *.pack

Tags: java, android, libgdx, texturepacker

Hi I have some problems with the texture atlas packer assetmanager from libgdx.... maybe someone had the same issue...
I pack my textures in my desktop app like this ... which is running and the pack files are generated...

```
public class DesktopLauncher {
private static boolean rebuildAtlas = false;
private static boolean drawDebugOutline = true;

public static void main (String[] arg) {
    if (rebuildAtlas) {
        Settings settings = new Settings();
        settings.maxWidth = 1024;
        settings.maxHeight = 1024;
        settings.duplicatePadding = false;
        settings.debug = drawDebugOutline;
        TexturePacker.process(settings, "asset_raw/images", "../android/assets/images", "ppack.pack");
    }
```

in my assetloader class i load this or i try too ...

```
public void init (AssetManager assetManager) {
    this.assetManager = assetManager;

    // set asset manager error handler
    assetManager.setErrorListener(this);
    assetManager.load("../android/assets/images/ppack.pack",TextureAtlas.class);


    // start loading assets and wait until finished
    assetManager.finishLoading();
    Gdx.app.debug(TAG, "# of assets loaded: "+ assetManager.getAssetNames().size);
    for (String a : assetManager.getAssetNames())
        Gdx.app.debug(TAG, "asset: " + a);

    TextureAtlas atlas = assetManager.get(../android/assets/images/ppack.pack");
```

...

However i get the error :

```
com.mygdx.game.Assets: Couldn't load asset '../android/assets/images/ppack.pack'
```

But the file exist and has no strange upper lower or antoher strange symbol in its name

any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

solved it by setting the working directory to .../gdx/first;
and loading the ppack.atlas and not the .pack

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't need

*"../android/assets/"*

remove this part. If you get the error again check your **Working Directory** under ***Run/Debug configurations*** (Android Studio) and specify your assets folder.

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets

Comment: i changed my working directory to the asset folder but still got the error -.- Current working directory in Java : ...\gdx\first\android\assets
, and the error com.mygdx.game.Assets: Couldn't load asset '/ppack.pack'
com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: File not found: \ppack.pack (Internal)

Comment: Are you trying to execute the desktop application?

Comment: assetManager.load("images/ppack.pack",TextureAtlas.class);
assetManager.get("images/ppack.pack",TextureAtlas.class);